# I am having trouble with centering the heading of a paragraph

Tags: html

```css
.center {
    text-align: center
}
```

```html
<h1 class="center">Title</h1>
<div style="float: left;">
<p>Some Text</p>
</div>
<div style="float: right;">
<img src="image.png">
</div>
```

When I run this code the heading appears on the center of the page. However, I want the heading to center above the paragraph. Can anyone help me do this?

Comment: How should the result look like?

Comment: Use something like flexbox.

Comment: So are you saying that the paragraph doesn't use the whole width of the page? Because that's the reference for centering the title, of course. If that's the case, then you need the paragraph and title to be both in the same container, like a `div`.

Comment: move the heading above the paragraph in the div?

Answer (score 1):

Try with following:

```html
  <div style="float: left;">
    <h1 class="center">Title</h1>
    <div>
      <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div style="float: right;">
    <img src="image.png">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### USE FLEXBOX

I recommend you ditch floats and use modern flex-box for alignment. You will find there is much greater depth of control.

```css
.row-wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.p-wrap {
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.p-wrap h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.img-wrap {
  flex: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-wrap">
  <div class="p-wrap">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Some Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="img-wrap">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvyJq.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it with a table:

```css
.center {
  text-align: center
 }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="center"><h1>Your title</h1></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Your Paragraph</p><img src="image.png" style="float: right"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: [don't use tables for layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html)